# Why is my csv file path always returning null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, filepath

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC project where users can insert csv and excel records in a database and edit it afterwards. I have finished the excel part and it is working splendidly. But on the other hand my csv version does not even manage to take the csv file path and it always return null. I have tried different approaches but none seem to work.

My wish is to keep the excel version and the csv version similar and so I used httpPost on both but for some reason it does not manage to get the csv file path.
Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

This is my home controller view that is supposed to send the file path:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "CSVImport", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        Select a file <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload CSV" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

And this here is my csv importer:

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.ProviderBase;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace BFProj2.Controllers
{
    public class CSVImportController : Controller
    {

        // GET: CSVImport
        //public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase csv_file_path)
        {
             DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
             if (csv_file_path != null && Request.Files["csv_file_path"].ContentLength > 0)
             {
             try
            {
                using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path.InputStream))
                {

                    //Solution to HDR problem: When getting to the checkbox part of the application, just keep the HDR unchecked.
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    //Can be true depending on if the csv document rows are enclosed in quotes or not. Delimiters are set as either ; or , depending on weather the csv columns are split with ; or , 
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn Titel = new DataColumn(column);
                        Titel.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(Titel);

                        DataColumn LastName = new DataColumn(column);
                        LastName.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(LastName);

                        DataColumn AbstrNum = new DataColumn(column);
                        AbstrNum.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(AbstrNum);

                        DataColumn PosterTitel = new DataColumn(column);
                        PosterTitel.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(PosterTitel);

                        DataColumn Workshop = new DataColumn(column);
                        Workshop.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(Workshop);

                        DataColumn Keywords = new DataColumn(column);
                        Keywords.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(Keywords);

                        DataColumn Institution = new DataColumn(column);
                        Institution.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(Institution);

                        DataColumn CollabEmail = new DataColumn(column);
                        CollabEmail.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(CollabEmail);

                    }
                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);

                    }
                    csvData = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();

            ViewData.Model = csvData.AsEnumerable();
                }
            }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

             }
             }

            return View();

        }
        }
    }
```

I took some source material from this:
http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using.html

I have not yet put in the bulk copy part and it is only a DataTable, but I want to make it so that it does everything in the controller before returning to the homecontroller view again instead of placing it somewhere else.

By the way, I am pretty new to stackoverflow so if there is something else I am doing wrong related to the question asking I would need directions to change it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I may be reading this wrong but should your `<input type="file">` be named `csv_file_path` rather than `file`?

Comment: Ah, thank you. You are right, might be slightly code blind, so if I change csv_file_path to file it will recognize the file path?

Comment: It did not work. The file path still returns null.

Comment: did you change `Request.Files["file"]` too? (you should also be able to just do `file.ContentLength` - the `HttpPostedFileBase` contains everything you need)

Comment: Now it worked, thank you! Missed the one in request.Files.

Comment: Now how do I mark you as answer? And close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post a file, the name of the `<input>` is used as the key for `Request.Files` and the parameter name for the action method, so these need to match. In your case, you have `<input name="file">` but parameter name `csv_file_path`. So you need to rename one or the other:

```
<input name="file">

public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
    ...
}
```

or

```
<input name="csv_file_path">

public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase csv_file_path)
{
    if (csv_file_path != null && Request.Files["csv_file_path"].ContentLength > 0)
    ...
}
```

Note you also do not need to use `Request.Files` - the HttpPostedFileBase has what you need:

```
    if (csv_file_path != null && csv_file_path.ContentLength > 0)
```